# Delete a Portion of a CSV Cell in Python

Tags: python, csv

I have recently stumbled upon a task utilizing some CSV files that are, to say the least, very poorly organized, with one cell containing what should be multiple separate columns. I would like to use this data in a Python script but want to know if it is possible to delete a portion of the row (all of it after a certain point) then write that to a dictionary.

Although I can't show the exact contents of the CSV, it looks like this:

```
useful. useless useless useless useless
```

I understand that this will most likely require either a regular expression or an `endswith` statement, but doing all of that to a CSV file is beyond me. Also, the period written after *useful* on the CSV should be removed as well, and is not a typo.

Comment: it is a bit unclear how you distinguish what is useful/useless. Do you wish to remove everything after one character comes up i.e. "." or everything after a fixed number of characters/words?

Comment: @user2640045 I would like to remove everything after the "." character. Sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: how exactly do you want that safed in a dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the character you want to split on you can use this simple method:

```
good_data = bad_data.split(".")[0] 
good_data = good_data.strip() # remove excess whitespace at start and end
```

This method will always work. `split` will return a tuple which will always have at least 1 entry (the full string).  Using `index` may throw an exception.

You can also limit the # of splits that will happen if necessary using `split(".", N)`.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

```
>>> "good.bad.ugly".split(".", 1)
['good', 'bad.ugly']
>>> "nothing bad".split(".")
['nothing bad']
>>> stuff = "useful useless"
>>> stuff = stuff[:stuff.index(".")]
ValueError: substring not found
```

Answer (score 0):

### Actual Answer

Ok then notice that you can use indexing for strings just like you do for lists. I.e. `"this is a very long string but we only want the first 4 letters"[:4]` gives `"this"`. If we now new the index of the dot we could just get what you want like that. For exactly that strings have the `index` method. So in total you do:

```
stuff = "useful. useless useless useless useless"
stuff = stuff[:stuff.index(".")]
```

Now stuff is very useful :).
In case we are talking about a file containing multiple lines like that you could do it for each line. Split that line at `,` and put all in a dictionary.

```
data = {}
with open("./test.txt") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f.read().split("\n")):
       csv_line = line[:line.index(".")]
       for j,col in enumerate(csv_line.split(",")):
            data[(i,j)] = col
```

### How one would do this

Notice that most people would not want to do it by hand. It is a common task to work on tabled data and there is a library called pandas for that. Maybe it would be a good idea to familiarise yourself a bit more with python before you dive into `pandas` though. I think a good point to start is [this](https://www.youtube.com/user/schafer5). Using `pandas` your task would look like this

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv("./test.txt", comment=".")
```

giving you what is called a dataframe.